# UNITY - Configuration Time (Fixed Timestep = 0.002) and DefaultContactOffset 0.0001

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

In a pool game, in which the collisions are fast, I am using a value equal to 0.0001 for the DefaultContactOffset and the Time as shown in the image. The game runs fine but slow, does anyone know how I could get the same result without losing game performance?

[image]

Comment: Why use timescale 2?

Comment: @derHugo With 1 it works too